# Gitlab partially deleted - Recover repo's

Tags: linux, ubuntu, git, apt, gitlab

I have a private Gitlab server on a Ubuntu machine. Now I, for some reason, accidentally partially uninstalled Gitlab by executing a mistyped apt-get command. I don't know which one exactly, but it started removing Gitlab from the system. I immediately saw something was wrong so I CTRL-C'd my way out of the command.

Few facts:

- Gitlab isn't working any more
- The command gitlab-ctl doesn't exist anymore
- In the /etc/gitlab folder I see gitlab-secrets.json, gitlab.rb, gitlab.rb.save, gitlab.rb.save.1 and a folder trusted-certs
- In /opt/gitlab I see 6 folders: embedded, etc, init, service, sv and var
- In /var/opt/gitlab I see backups  bootstrapped  git-data  gitlab-ci  gitlab-rails  gitlab-shell: gitlab-workhorse  logrotate  nginx  postgresql  redis  trusted-certs-directory-hash
- I stopped the uninstallation after about 5 seconds

I sadly didn't make any backups of the Gitlab server, but the Gitlab was used heavily, and I need my data back.

I know the GIT repo's are in /var/opt/gitlab/git-data. And I assume the database is in /var/opt/gitlab/postgresql.

Can I recover my Gitlab and it's data (MR's, commits etc)? If so, how would I go about doing so? I assume the data is there, but it's partially uninstalled. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling it?

Comment: No, I'm afraid I will lose the data from the previous one, because I don't know what reinstalling will delete / keep.

Comment: Good point. That's one reason why I don't use Debian-based distributions. (Red Hat-based distributions _always_ leave your data and configuration when you uninstall a program.)

Comment: Mind explaining why I'm downvoted?

Answer (score 1):

Right, after making a full server backup, I simply reinstalled Gitlab via apt-get, and after a reboot the entire Gitlab server was working, with all the old repo's, users, MR's and commits.

So after all it was way easier than expected.